# Question about Logical implication

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose $A$ is a set of propositional formulas, and suppose $\varphi$ is a propositional formula. In my textbook they write $A \models \varphi$, if for every truth assignment $w$ such that $w(\psi) = 1$ for every $\psi \in A$, we also have $w(\varphi)=1$.

They now ask me to show that $\emptyset\models \varphi$ if and only if $\varphi$ is a tautology. But how can I show this? The definition tells us nothing about empty $A$?

Comment: If $A=\emptyset$, then every truth assignment $w$ satisfies $w(\psi)=1$ for every $\psi\in A$, because there are no such $\psi$. Thus $\emptyset\models\varphi$ if and only if $w(\varphi)=1$ for every truth assignment $w$.

Comment: @walcher, But if there is no such $\psi$ why does $\varphi$ have to be a tautology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $A = \varnothing$. Then, for *any* truth value assignment $w$, $w(\psi) = 1$ (vacuously) for each and every $\psi \in A = \varnothing$

Why? 
Because there *are no* $\psi \in A = \varnothing$. So the hypothesis is satisfied vacuously, because it is *not possible* for there to *exist* any $\psi \in \varnothing$ such that $w(\psi) \neq 1$.

Hence $\varnothing \models \varphi$ *if and only if* for each truth value assignment $w$, $w(\varphi) =  1$, too. This holds if and only if $\varphi$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice opportunity to illustrate for the novice the role of *proof strategies* in reasoning mathematically about logical claims.

Notice, first of all, that the definition of [entailment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) $\models$, if put in negative terms, says that to prove that $A\models\varphi$ *fails to hold* one has to find some truth-assignment $v$ that simultaneously satisfies $A$ and does not satisfy $\varphi$.
Furthermore, recall that $v$ is said to satisfy a given set of formulas $A$ if $v(\psi)=1$ for every $\psi\in A$; thus, [*contrapositively*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), we may say that $A$ is *not* satisfied by $v$ if there is some $\psi\in A$ that is not satisfied by $v$, that is, such that $v(\psi)=0$.

**[Lemma]** Any truth-assignment $v$ satisfies the empty set of formulas.
*Proof.* To assert that the empty set $\emptyset$ is not satisfied by a given truth-assignment $v$ would require us first of all to *find* some formula $\psi$ in $\emptyset$ with a certain property (namely, the property of not being satisfied by $v$).  But this is an impossible task, as there are *no* formulas in the empty set! 
(Incidentally, this is precisely what it means to say that a certain property is [*vacuously true*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).)

**[Main Claim: one direction]** ($\emptyset\models \varphi$) implies that ($\varphi$ is a tautology).
*Proof.* Suppose, [*by contraposition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive), that $\varphi$ is not a [tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29), that is, suppose that there is some truth-assignment $w$ such that $w(\varphi)=0$.  By the previous Lemma, we alread know that $w$ satisfies the empty set $\emptyset$.  Thus, by the definition of entailment, $\emptyset\models \varphi$ fails to hold.

**[Main Claim: other direction]** ($\varphi$ is a tautology) implies that ($\emptyset\models \varphi$).
*Proof.* Assume that $\varphi$ is a tautology, that is, assume that $v(\varphi)=1$ for every truth-assignment $v$.  Suppose now [*by reductio*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum) that $\emptyset\models \varphi$ fails to hold.  It follows, *in particular* that there is some truth-assignment $w$ such that $w(\varphi)=0$ (the failure of $\emptyset\models \varphi$ also entails, in particular, that such $w$ satisfies $\emptyset$, but that is innocuous and known anyway to be true, from the above Lemma), that is, we are given a truth-assignment that does not satisfy $\varphi$.  This immediately contradicts the assumption about the tautological character of $\varphi$.

PS: The exhaustive amount of detail in the above proofs usually reduce to something like one- or two-line arguments as students get more and more experienced in producing them.